# Why is VLC lagging when playing MP3 files over my LAN?

Tags: macos, mp3, vlc-media-player, audio-streaming

I'm using VLC 1.1.7 on Mac OS X 10.6.8 for listening to MP3s stored on my NAS, which is a QNAP device. My MacBook Pro is connected via Gigabit LAN over a Linksys WRT-610N router.

**Problem:**

Every file I play lags every minute or so. There's a short delay or glitch, then it continues to play. How can I get VLC to stream them correctly? Can I enable some buffer?

**Things I've checked:**

- It plays local files fine without a problem
- The network connection itself is not the issue (the NAS streams HD movies to a TV just fine)
- It occurs on both SMB and AFP mounted shares

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible that the values for file cache times are too low. To be on the safe side, the buffer can be made larger.

Go to *Preferences* and navigate to the *Input / Codecs* tab. Click the *Show All* button.

Ensure *Input and Codecs* is selected in the sidebar and scroll way down to the *Advanced* section. In *Network caching* slider, enter larger values than the default ones. I found 1000ms for Local and 3000ms for Network to be sane. If you still see stuttering, try progressively larger values until playback is smooth.

[image]

Click the *Save* button. It might be necessary to restart VLC. Now you don't have any playback problems anymore.

Comment: any idea where this open has gone too? It's not present in 2.1.5 version of VLC.

Comment: @MarkTomlin The option is now resides under `Input / Codecs` directly as of `2.1.5`.